# iOS — Is there any way to send a gift to a user of another App Store?

Tags: ios-appstore, gift

> The recipient of your gift must have an Apple ID in your country or
> region. For example, if you're in the United States, you can't send a
> gift to a friend who lives in Australia.

I'd like to send an app gift (a game), but I'm in Germany an the recipient is in Russia. Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way around what you've already found.  Different countries have different rules so Apple enforces the rule when gifting apps.

You can send an [Apple Gift Card](https://www.apple.com/shop/gift-cards) to the recipient to have them buy the game.

Comment: Would that need to be a Russian Apple Gift Card?

Comment: @Gilby I'm pretty sure it has to be a Gift Card from russian store.